# Problems with ffmpeg command line on android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I managed to compile the ffmpeg Static build. But when I am trying to call the ffmpeg command line I get a Java IOException: No such file or Directory.

My code is as follows:

```
public void merge_video(View view){

    if(ffmpeg_file.exists()){
          Log.d(null, "ffmpeg exists");
      }else{
          Log.d(null, "Could not locate ffmpeg in the folder");
      }

      File file1 = new File("/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/VID_3_25_2013_12_22.mp4");
      if(file1.exists()){
          Log.d(null,"File 1 exists");
      }
      File file2 = new File("/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/VID_3_25_2013_12_28.mp4");
      if(file2.exists()){
          Log.d(null,"File 2 exists");
      }

      String[] ffmpegCommand = new String[5];
      ffmpegCommand[0] = "/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/ffmpeg";
      ffmpegCommand[1] = "-i";
      ffmpegCommand[2] = "concat:/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/VID_3_25_2013_12_22.mp4|/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/VID_3_25_2013_12_28.mp4";
      ffmpegCommand[3] = "copy";
      ffmpegCommand[4] = "/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/output.mp4";  

      try {
          Process ffmpegProcess = new ProcessBuilder(ffmpegCommand).redirectErrorStream(true).start();

          String line;
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ffmpegProcess.getInputStream()));
          Log.d(null, "*******Starting FFMPEG");

          while((line = reader.readLine())!=null){

              Log.d(null, "***"+line+"***"); 
          }
          Log.d(null,"****ending FFMPEG****");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

The LogCat print is as follows:

```
03-27 20:41:10.522: W/System.err(24709): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/ffmpeg, -i, concat:/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/VID_3_25_2013_12_22.mp4|/mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/VID_3_25_2013_12_28.mp4, copy, /mnt/sdcard/com.ffmpeg_test/output.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: [ANDROID_SOCKET_zygote=13, TMPDIR=/data/local/tmp, ANDROID_BOOTLOGO=1, EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard, ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app, PATH=/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin, ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec, LOOP_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/obb, BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar, USBHOST_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard/usbStorage, ANDROID_DATA=/data, LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib, ANDROID_ROOT=/system, ANDROID_PROPERTY_WORKSPACE=12,32768, EXTERNAL_STORAGE2=/mnt/sdcard/external_sd]
03-27 20:41:10.522: W/System.err(24709):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:224)
03-27 20:41:10.522: W/System.err(24709):    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:202)
03-27 20:41:10.522: W/System.err(24709):    at com.example.ffmpeg_test.MainActivity.merge_video(MainActivity.java:106)
03-27 20:41:10.522: W/System.err(24709):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 20:41:10.522: W/System.err(24709):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-27 20:41:10.527: W/System.err(24709):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2149)
03-27 20:41:10.527: W/System.err(24709):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
03-27 20:41:10.527: W/System.err(24709):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
03-27 20:41:10.527: W/System.err(24709):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-27 20:41:10.527: W/System.err(24709):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-27 20:41:10.527: W/System.err(24709):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-27 20:41:10.527: W/System.err(24709):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
03-27 20:41:10.527: W/System.err(24709):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 20:41:10.527: W/System.err(24709):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-27 20:41:10.532: W/System.err(24709):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:847)
03-27 20:41:10.532: W/System.err(24709):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
03-27 20:41:10.537: W/System.err(24709):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 20:41:10.537: W/System.err(24709): Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
03-27 20:41:10.537: W/System.err(24709):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
03-27 20:41:10.537: W/System.err(24709):    at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:222)
03-27 20:41:10.537: W/System.err(24709):    ... 16 more
03-27 20:41:36.057: W/KeyCharacterMap(24709): No keyboard for id 0
03-27 20:41:36.057: W/KeyCharacterMap(24709): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

Comment: try running it from a sub folder of /data/local

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android has a special security feature: the /mnt/sdcard filesystem is execution-protected. You cannot run an executable that is located on the external storage (a.k.a. USB storage). If you want to run ffmpeg binary on your device, you must load it into one of the internal directories. For example, you can pack it into **libs/armeabi** of your Java project, so that the installer will automatically unpack it into the **/data/data/<your package>/lib** directory on the device. Or you can find another directory, like **/data/local**, where you can put the executable binary file with **adb push**

Comment: same issue!!
I am merging two videos which are at internal storage and storing the resulting video on the same location but it gives this-java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Comment: I think this answer might solve my problem but I don't know how to do these stuffs

Comment: @AkashDubey: to check if this is *the same issue*, run **ffmpeg** with no file parameters, e.g. `fffmpeg -?`. If you still get same java exception, it's it. If not, your problem is different, and has to do with the way you specify input or output file paths. In the latter case, feel free to open a separate question and disclose more details on how you attempt to run **ffmpeg** from your app.

Comment: I was executing it directly,
First I need to Load the binary then execute,
Now it takes very much time to merge videos!!

Comment: @AkashDubey sorry I cannot understand your question.

Comment: @AlexCohn don't worry, I wasn't asking i was just telling that I was executing ffmpeg command before loading ffmpeg, that was the issue and now it is resolved